# How can I get the calculated field work in Angular 2?

Tags: angular2-template

I am trying to get the data from a calculated field

```
export class Position {
   securityId: number;
   securityName: string;
   tradeCount: number;
   avgPrice: number;
   quantity: number;


    constructor () {}

    public get marketValue(): number {
        return this.avgPrice * this.quantity;
    }
}
```

And I am tryinhg  to bind all the fields which work fine but the calculated marketValue does not

```
td>{{ position.marketValue | currency:"USD":true:"1.2-2"}}</td>
```

The table cell shows empty. However the following does work

```
td>{{ this.quantity * this.avgPrice | currency:"USD":true:"1.2-2"}}</td>
```

How can I get the caclcualed property to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
td>{{ position.marketValue | currency:"USD":true:"1.2-2"}}</td>
```

to

```
td>{{ this.marketValue | currency:"USD":true:"1.2-2"}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Position {
   securityId: number;
   securityName: string;
   tradeCount: number;
   avgPrice: number;
   quantity: number;
   marketValue: number;

    constructor () {}

    ngOnChanges(change)  {
        this.marketValue = this.avgPrice * this.quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Arash, R U suggesting to implement OnChange ? I tried your proposed solution however it did not work, there is no change trigger - all the values are to be set at initialization.  also tried AfterViewInit

        import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

        export class Position implements AfterViewInit {
        //..
        avgPrice: number;
        quantity: number;
        marketValue: number;

            constructor () {}

            ngAfterViewInit()  {
                this.marketValue = this.avgPrice * this.quantity;
            }
        }